# Motorcycle rear wheel stuck after being unused for a few years

Tags: motorcycle, clutch

I'm trying to get my old bike up and running again after a few years of waiting, mostly outside, covered but still subject to all kinds of weather.
When i parked it it was fully functional,  but now, I'vre tried to move it and it looks like the rear wheel is really stuck. 
Any ideas where to start investigating, what to try, in order to at least get it moving so i can take it into a shop.
It's a Suzuki Savaga LS650, from 1998.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This may sound silly, but is it in gear? Also, is the wheel not moving or the transmission? In other words, if there were no belt on it, would the wheel turn freely?

Answer (score 2):

It is most probably the pads stuck to the disc - apparently from the comments (thanks ...) it is a drum brake, at least that is what I would start with.

After that, check the rear wheel bearings.

Comment: This bike as expanding rear brakes, not disc. Hopefully not rusted to the drum inside. That would make it more difficult than dealing with disc.

Comment: @CharlieRB - No lie. I'd think those types would lock up well before a disk ... more surface area to rust/corrode. Wouldn't doubt that is the issue.

Comment: If it is a drum brake, then that will be Challenge... it’s bad enough when tgere is just a ridge to deal with...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the transmission is in neutral and see if it moves. If not, pull the clutch lever in and see if it moves. If not, I would put the bike on the center stand. Loosen the tug bolts and axle to remove the drive belt tension. See if there is any rotation in the wheel. This eliminates the transmission as the issue. If the wheel still doesn't turn the issue is likely the brake shoes are rusted to the drum (most likely cause) or the axle/hub bearings are seized.